# does VS express conflict with professional?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I just recently installed VS 2008 Professional on my computer and I already have C++ and C# express on my computer. But for some strange reason I can not find the executable for VS professional 2008. when I go into program files and look under visual studios 2008. All i see is a bunch of tools but no vs 2008 exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange...

have you check the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe?

Comment: There it is. I wonder why they put it there and not somewhere easy where people can find it.

Comment: @numerical25, if this answer is correct then it indicates you have Visual Studio 2010 installed, not 2008

Answer (score 2):

The expression and professional SKUs do not conflict and can be installed together.  For the non-express SKU's (i.e. professional) the executable program is named `devenv.exe`.  It will be located under

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Or an a 64 bit machine

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe